# Options_for_select not working: dropdown box for boolean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to include a boolean value as a dropdown box using the following code in my edit view:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
  <%= f.select :match, options_for_select([['On', true], ['Off', false]]), class: 'form-control input-md' %>
</div>
```

However I'm experiencing two problems:

1.It does not display the correct value. Even when the user's value is `false`, it still displays `On`.

2.It does not implement the styling. The inspector shows that it implements it as follows:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
  <select name="user[match]" id="user_match">
    <option value="true">On</option>
    <option value="false">Off</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: When loading the edit view, it should have the value selected for that user: so if the record's value is `true`, then `On` should be selected. And if `false` then `Off` should be selected. Now `On` is always selected irrespective of the record's value.

Comment: how do you store the match value in your db?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
<%= f.select :match, options_for_select([['On', true], ['Off', false]], selected: your_object.match),{}, {class: 'form-control input-md'} %>
```

Comment: Great, happy to help you  :)